# Liferay + glassfish 3.1.1 + CAS + SSL, SSL error in liferay

Tags: ssl, glassfish, liferay, cas

- I am trying to integrate CAS on Liferay.
- I have separate CAS server running in secure port but i am using self-signed certificate
- I have a Liferay-6.1 in another server bundled with glassfish-3.1.1 server.
- I have imported required key file from CAS server using java keytool in server where Liferay is hosted

But I keep getting **SSL error** while trying to integrate from liferay CAS configuration page.

In my opinion, here glassfish is to be blamed because I have successfully configured and tested the same CAS server in Liferay-6.1 bundled with jboss-7.0 and also tested in liferay6.1 bundled with tomcat. 
I tested all liferay bundles in the same server which means there is no error in importing certificate keys.

does anybody have anyidea how can I successfully configure secure CAS in liferay bundled with glassfish?

**EDIT**:

I traced the error and it is:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I remember this particular error while configuring self signed certificate before importing keys in other liferay bundles (jboss and tomcat). But it was gone after I imported CAS keys in keystore.

Comment: Which keystore did you import the cert into on glassfish?  There are two in the domain/config directory on glassfish, cacerts.jks and keystore.jks.  Did you point the glassfish ssl listener at the new cert's alias?

Comment: Earlier, I imported into jvm's cacerts file. I didn't realize glassfish uses it's own keystore and not jvm's.

Now, I imported the key into domain/config/cacerts.jsk file and it worked perfectly. 
Thanks @Jim, Can I mark your comment as an answer? :)

Comment: I don't know how to make a comment be the answer, so I copied it to an answer.  Glad it helped!

Comment: Make sure you set the glassfish master password.  (asadmin change-master-password)  When you do that, you'll probably need to change the password on the cert in the keystore too.  I mention this because this has caused me grief before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied from my comment:

Which keystore did you import the cert into on glassfish? There are two in the domain/config directory on glassfish, cacerts.jks and keystore.jks. Did you point the glassfish ssl listener at the new cert's alias?